# Responsive way to place 2 pictures over each other like Facebook and google plus

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying hardly to position an image above the another image using bootstrap , while I can't find a responsive way to create it.
My target design is this
[image: target design]

I found that all the user questions were answered with a position thing in css. All there answers were not mobile friendly so can anyone help

Comment: Would you please post the code you're working with so that we may better understand the issue and help you out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be needing media queries for this. You can also use negative margin if you don't want to use positioning.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fb-profile">
        <img align="left" class="fb-image-lg" src="http://lorempixel.com/850/280/nightlife/5/" alt="Profile image example"/>
        <img align="left" class="fb-image-profile thumbnail" src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/people/9/" alt="Profile image example"/>

    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->


.fb-profile img.fb-image-lg {
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;  
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

.fb-image-profile {
    margin: -90px 10px 0px 50px;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 20%; 
  }

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .fb-image-profile {
      margin: -45px 10px 0px 25px;
      z-index: 9;
      width: 20%; 
    }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/930/)

Answer (score 2):

Positioning seems unavoidable. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/sc47jm6r/)

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.small-round, .big-round {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.big-round {
  left: 10%;
  bottom: -60%;
}
.small-round {
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50%
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<img class='top' src='http://placehold.it/400x200' />
<img class='big-round' src='http://placehold.it/200/999' />
<img class='small-round' src='http://placehold.it/100/000' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To position an image between two sections, like in the request, here's what you need:

```css
body { margin: 0;}
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.has-image-after {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/800/400) no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  padding-bottom: calc(100px + 1rem);
  color: white;
}
.has-image-after + section {
  padding-top: calc(100px + 1rem);
}
.has-image-after .image-after {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-after img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .has-image-after .image-after {
    width: 33.3333vw;
    height: 33.3333vw;
  }
  .has-image-after {
    padding-bottom: calc(16.6667vw + 1rem);
  }
  .has-image-after + section {
    padding-top:  calc(16.6667vw + 1rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="has-image-after">
  <div class="content">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?
  </div>
  <div class="image-after">
    <img class="between-sections" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200" />
  </div>
  
</section>

<section><h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.</section>
```

It has the advantage of cropping the image to the largest available circle, without distorting it and without it having to be at a `1:1` width/height ratio.
Responsiveness is handled inside the `@media` query. Feel free to change it to meet your specific use-case.

---

And, to make it more adaptable, here's some `SCSS`. Change values to whatever you need and parse (test in <kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/a5jwckjg/)</kbd>):

```css
$sectionPadding: 1rem;
$imageWidth: 200px;
$imageResponsiveWidth: 33.3333vw;
$breakPoint: 600px;
$left: 20%;
$bottom: -40px;

body { margin: 0;}
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: $sectionPadding;
}
.has-image-after {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: calc((#{$imageWidth/2} + #{$sectionPadding}) + #{$bottom});
}
.has-image-after + section {
  padding-top: calc((#{$imageWidth/2} + #{$sectionPadding}) - #{$bottom});
}
.has-image-after .image-after {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: $imageWidth;
  height: $imageWidth;
  left: $left;
  bottom: $bottom;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-after img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
@media(max-width: $breakPoint) {
  .has-image-after .image-after {
    width: $imageResponsiveWidth;
    height: $imageResponsiveWidth;
  }
  .has-image-after {
    padding-bottom: calc((#{$imageResponsiveWidth/2} + #{$sectionPadding}) + #{$bottom});
  }
  .has-image-after + section {
    padding-top:  calc((#{$imageResponsiveWidth/2} + #{$sectionPadding}) - #{$bottom});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Gerard's answer was the best. You're going to want to use positioning, by making the parent container position: relative; and then absolutely positioning the images inside the parent container.

I prefer this over using negative top margin as vijayscode suggested. However, vijayscode is correct in that you will most likely need to use css media queries to resize and reposition those elements on different screen sizes.

So I would use Gerards code example, but also use media queries. Would be able to provide a more specific answer if you had provided your code.